# XCTMemoryMetric not recording memory in iOS Unit Testing bundle in Xcode 12.5 (XCTest)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

#### Background

I have implemented a `Swift` algorithm in which I want to consume low memory at runtime (Space Complexity). So, I wanted to write performance tests using `XCTMemoryMetric` as part of a "Unit Testing Bundle" for large input sizes. I need to track regressions and optimisations for this algorithm, so I wanted initially to track the baseline metrics and expected this to work out of the box for my iOS app. Unfortunately, even after reading the Apple documentation for [Performance Tests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/performance_tests?language=swift), I haven't found any potential fixes or information to help me resolve my particular issue.

I am using an iOS Base SDK for my main target (`UIKit` and `Storyboard`) and the same Base SDK for my "Unit Testing Bundle" in Xcode. In Xcode, I have left the default "Build active architecture only" setting to "Yes", and the main target compiles as well, and the tests compile fine. However, when I finish running the `measure` block with an `XCTMemoryMetric()` and `XCTClockMetric()` added as the only parameters, the Memory metrics don't show up in the test report. The Clock metrics are also completely unreliable, and my test fails (almost) every time due to high standard deviations even with the same function! Anyway, this question is focused on the memory metric.

**Example of successful compilation:**
[image: example of successful compilation]

**Note:** I have also tried other metrics like `XCTCPUMetric` for performance testing, which doesn't show results either.

**Example of missing memory metrics:**
[image: example of missing memory metrics]

I don't get warning messages in the console or exceptions.

#### What I've tried:

1. Moving the algorithm to a `Swift Package Target` and moving performance tests to a `Package Unit Testing Bundle` - the memory metric shows up in the test logs. Still, it is highly unreliable (sometimes showing even **negative** memory allocation !). This solution is not ideal since I don't want to create a package just for a single algorithm.
2. Moving the algorithm to a `Mac-only Target` with correlated `Unit Testing Bundle` - works but again not appropriate for an iOS-only app.
3. Debugging using `metric.reportMeasurements()` shows a missing `_data` parameter in the metric and crashes at runtime:

[image: example of runtime crash when reporting]

4. Running individual test cases instead of the whole suite didn't make a difference.
5. Testing even larger input array sizes didn't make a difference.

Is there any clean way I can resolve my issue without changing my Base SDK? I am considering abandoning `XCTest` for performance testing since it doesn't seem to work very well, but ideally, I'd like to stick with Apple's recommended APIs.  You can also see the code seems to run completely on Stack Memory (no `static let`s or `var`s), so I don't think the confusion between Stack and Heap Memory is the root cause.

#### Code:

I've posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/LemonSpike/0e869a6df291190a34322a0bfbf19726) of the algorithm I'm performance testing since the code is too many lines to include here. Even with other (less memory-intensive) code inside the `measure` block, the issue is reproducible for me.

The test code:

```
func testPerformanceExample() {
    let metric = XCTMemoryMetric()
    measure(metrics: [metric],
            block: {
      var sums: [[[Int]]] = []
      (1...100).forEach { _ in
        sums.append(QOneSolutionOne().fourSum([1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 2, 3, -3, 0, 4,
                                               -2, 5, -4, 6, -6, 7, -8, 8, -7],
                                              target: 0))
      }
    })
  }
```

I think this may be an `XCTest` bug, but I wanted to see if I am missing something. Open to any advice, thanks.

Comment: did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: I used a separate [library](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections-benchmark) for performance tests instead. The benchmarks were more reliable using the swift cli rather than XCTest.

Comment: I use XCTest to mainly measure performance in UI Tests. Is this library capable to measure CPU and memory usage during UI tests?

Comment: No, the library doesn’t support UI tests with XCTest.